# Basic data types not recognized in IDL v.8.7.2

Tags: idl-programming-language

My IDL installation (currently v.8.7.2, but the same problem occurred in v.8.5) does not recognize `hash`, `list`, `dictionary` and `orderedhash`. For example, typing

```
h = HASH('Id', 1234)
```

results in the error "Variable is undefined: HASH.". I am at my wits end. All kinds of other things are working with no problems, I don't seem to have issues with my path or with external libraries. What's going on??

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your path is not correct, that it is pointing at the IDL lib directory of an older (pre-hash, list, etc) IDL's lib directory. Could you print `!path`?

Comment: Yes, this problem was finally solved by adding the following line to the .bash_profile: export IDL_PATH=+/Applications/idl/installation/dir:+/Users/personal/libraries:$IDL_PATH. But what a nontrivial manifestation of the problem, when so much of the IDL functionality was working and just these few select data types weren't!

Comment: Just add "<IDL_DEFAULT>" to your path and it will add the appropriate IDL lib directory.